# How do I enable end-users to run multiple instances of an AIR desktop application?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have been told is not possible to run multiple AIR instances, but unfortunately not until AFTER I have incorporated a lot of the AIR only api's into the app.

I have attempted to 'wrap' the application in an outer app, and instantiate native windows for each instance, but the singleton classes are all returning the same information.  Is there a way to load the windows into separate domains so a getInstance() call returns an instance unique to that particular window only?

Comment: I won't post this as an answer as I'm not 100% sure. I don't know if it would properly work on AIR, but custom ApplicationDomain is what you are searching for: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#applicationDomain Just create separate one for each app you load. On theory, it should be working :)

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to do, but I do not see a way to apply an application domain to a window....  using var win:myWindow = new MyWindow (assuming MyWindow is an instance of a <s:Window> how do I set the applicationDomain  or apply a loader?

Comment: Well you must load it externally in order to use the ApplicationDomain thing.. If you just compile and create instances - it's absolutely normal that everything runs in the same domain :) You need to either change the logic with that global class, or load external swfs..

Comment: Yes, it appears that my lack of a formal programming education and  miserably vague documentation (likely written under the assumption  that anyone who needed the directions would of course already possess a complete understanding of the material presented; isn't that what documentation is for?) have again combined to propel me full force down a blind alley  only to find the Adobe engineers snickering as they put the finishing touches on the 'You can't get there from HERE!' sign.

Comment: Now if only AIR created an accessible swf file....   HTML5, anyone?  AIR is as dead as Flex...

Comment: Haha don't be that negative.. Yes you are right AIR goes down, but it's still having it's positive sides.. Unfortunately it's exactly like searching for a path with covered eyes - you will eventually get there, but it will take time to learn all the hidden easter eggs they got for you.. Sorry, this is the situation..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AIR Application written using Singletons needs to spawn multiple instances of app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511751/air-application-written-using-singletons-needs-to-spawn-multiple-instances-of-ap)